# Preenchimento automático de TextBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho a tabela `AspNetUser` no meu banco de dados que eu uso para identificar e autorizar os logins.

Para efetuar login na minha página, o usuário precisa sempre digitar o **usuario@email.com**.

É possível programar a `TextBox` para preencher automaticamente o **"@email.com"** ?

Assim, o usuário precisaria apenas preencher na TextBox: **"usuario"**.

Quero seguir a mesma ideia do site da Google, onde não precisamos preencher o **@gmail.com**, basta digitar a primeira parte do e-mail.

Já tentei isso:

```
<script>
function autoCompletEmail() {
    var x = document.getElementById("email");
    x.value = x.value + "wstur.com";
}
```

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10" id="email" onblur="autoCompletEmail">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Use o evento onleave do textbox para completar com o @provedor.com

Comment: Obrigado. Você pode dar um exemplo de como usa? Sou novato nessa área de ASP NET MVC.

Answer (score 2):

Pode sempre usar o evento `onblur` e depois complementar o **@email.com** do lado do cliente:

```
<input type="text" id="email" onblur="addEmailSufix()">
```

Do lado do cliente:

```
<script>
    function addEmailSufix()
    {
        var x = document.getElementById("email");
        x.value = x.value + encodeURIComponent("@gmail.com");
    }
</script>
```

---

Utilizando o exemplo que colocou na sua questão:

```
<script>
    function autoCompleteEmail() {
        var x = document.getElementById("email");
        x.value = x.value + encodeURIComponent("@wstur.com");
    }
</script>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @id = "email", @class = "form-control", @onblur = "autoCompleteEmail();" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado. Tentei, mas não funcionou. O que está errado no meu código acima?

Comment: Adicionada nova solução à resposta!

Comment: Aparece esse erro: "Mensagem de Erro do Compilador: CS0103: The name 'wstur' does not exist in the current context". Dá erro quando eu coloco "@". Só passa "wstur.com".

Comment: Resposta editada :)

Comment: Obrigado. Mas, ainda não funcionou. O mesmo erro persiste.

Comment: Tente colocar uma barra "\" antes da @.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88186/discussion-between-joao-martins-and-dp-ws-receptivo).